# "???" вместо кириллицы в .exe Pascal ABC NET

Tags: pascal

Написал программу в Pascal ABC NET. В нем же и провел компиляцию в exeшник.
На этом же компьютере весь кириллический текст нормально отображается. Но на стороннем вместо русского текста выводит знаки вопроса. Как можно это решить?

Answer (score 0):

Вариант

```
Console.OutputEncoding := System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251);
```

не помогает?

Answer (score 0):

Еще может помочь пойти в Windows control panel, Languages/Языки, Administrative language settings / Адиминистративные установки языков, на вкладке Administrative надо выбрать Русский в качестве языка для non-unicode programs и перезагрузиться.